# Run sed script with paths (current path) in Jenkins pipelines

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need to replace some paths in several files:

Origin: /var/ww/html
Replacement: "current folder" : bash pwd

```
stage('Test: Static Analysis') {
    steps {
        sh "sed -i -e 's/\\/var\\/www\\/html/$WORKSPACE/g' reports/codereview/*.xml"
    }
}
```

I've also tried:

```
stage('Test: Static Analysis') {
    steps {
         script {
            def path = pwd();
            path = path.replace("\\/", "/");
            echo "Path: ${path}"
            sh "sed -i -e 's/\\/var\\/www\\/html/${path}/g' reports/codereview/*.xml"
         }
     }
}
```

How can I get the current directory with bash (pwd) or $WORKSPACE and escape the `/` with `\\/` ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did the trick:

```
sh "sed -i -e 's/\\/var\\/www\\/html/${WORKSPACE.replace('/', '\\/')}/g' reports/codereview/*.xml"
```